# Problem with encoding

Tags: font-encodings, input-encodings

I have a problem with my tex file encoding. In my text in tex file I have something like this:

```
1. Wykonuje zaw??d z kt??rego zupe??nie nie jest zadowolony.
```

Which should be:

```
1. Wykonuje zawód z którego zupełnie nie jest zadowolony.
```

The problem is with polish diactric signs as you can see. I've tried to change the encoding but it doesn't work and I really don't know what to do.

Thanks in advice for your help

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
%\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\title{T??umaczenie - ??galit?© entre hommes et femmes}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

1. Wykonuje zaw??d z kt??rego zupe??nie nie jest zadowolony.

2. Wsp????czynnik umieralnoÂ¶ci jest o wiele wiÄ?kszy ni?? ten urodzin.

3. Na poczÂ±tku roku cena ropy zaczÄ???a siÄ? obni??aÄ? a teraz wzrasta.

4. ZaprowadÄ? dziecko do nia??ki! 

5. Przesta??em karmiÄ? siÄ? z??udzeniami.

6. To danie jest bardzo po??ywne.

7. Rozw??j us??ug powoli poprawia siÄ?.

8. Istnieje wiele dysproporcji miÄ?dzy p??acami w firmach prywatnych i pa??stwowych.

9. Z tego starego zamku pozosta??o tylko rilka ruin.

10. Jakie sÂ± pana Â¶rodki na utrzymanie?

11. JeÂ¶li chodzi o mnie to muszÄ? wyznaÄ? ??e to dobry spos??b aby wyjÂ¶Ä? z kryzysu.

12. WiÄ?kszoÂ¶Ä? kobiet powinna pracowaÄ? na p???? etatu. 

13. MuszÄ? znieÂ¶Ä? konsekwencje mojego wyboru.

14. Pobra??em za te prace sporÂ± sumÄ?.

15. Ten kr??l pomno??y?? bogactwo swego kraju.

16. MogÄ? wykonywaÄ? r????ne zajÄ?cia domowe. 

17. WiÄ?kszoÂ¶Ä? czasu poÂ¶wiÄ?cam na pracÄ?, a poza tym czytam. 

18. MyslÄ?, ??e ta praca pozwoli mi nabyÄ? doÂ¶wiadczenia.

19. Pana liczne pobyty za granicÂ± sÂ± powa??nym osiÂ±gnieciem.

20. Cel zosta?? osiÂ±gniÄ?ty!

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like that you saved the file in the meantime with a wrong encoding. You can try to change your editors encoding. If it doesn't help then I suppose your file is damaged. However, you should switch completely to `utf8` instead of `latin1`

Comment: I tried my editors encoding and it didn't work. But how it is possible that each tex file that I open now has the same problem with wrong encoding?

Comment: The problem is your _editor_, it uses a different encoding.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be a wrong encoding setting in the text editor used by the OP.

Comment: Can you give me a tip that could solve my problem? If there is any? I should reinstall miktex or ...?